# Closing a popup window in Chrome doesn't seem to release memory

Tags: javascript, popup, window

I'm seeing some strange behavior in Chrome that I'm trying to verify is intended (or possibly a bug?). Here are the steps I took:

1. First I opened the Chrome task manager, right-clicked and selected "JavaScript memory"
2. Next I navigated to a test page that has a link that opens a new popup window when clicked
3. The popup window loads a page that includes a lot of large third-party JavaScript libraries
4. I checked the Chrome task manager and the JavaScript ram had increased significantly for the test page after opening the popup
5. Finally, I closed the popup window and waited, but the memory usage basically stayed where it was at.

If I clicked the link on the test page multiple times to open multiple popup windows, closing them doesn't seem to lower the memory usage.

I tried this test in IE and Firefox, and when closing the popups in those browsers the memory usage goes down as expected.

Comment: If you click on the trashcan icon in the Timeline screen of Developer Tools, does that reduce the memory?

Comment: No, the memory usage doesn't really go down

Answer (score 0):

First off, it's great that you identified an action that you think is causing the leak! This is the first step in tracking down your problem, since it gives you a specific scenario to test before / after.

Since you already confirmed with the Task Manager that the memory is not being released, the next step is to do a Timeline recording:

1. Open your application on the page where the leak occurs and start the DevTools
2. Go to the Timeline tab in the DevTools and click Start Recording; Also, press the "Garbage" icon right now, to make sure Garbage Collection is triggered before you do your recording
3. In the application, open the dialog and then close it; you can also do this multiple times
4. Back to the DevConsole, click the "Garbage" icon again and then stop the recording

What do you see? Do you see in the Memory lane that it is never going doing? Or is the memory at the end the same as when you started?

Make sure to check the [official DevTools documentation](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/profile/memory-problems/memory-diagnosis#visualize-memory-leaks-with-timeline-recordings) for more info on using the Timeline and other tools to find common memory leaks.

Comment: The memory doesn't go down when looking at the timeline, but my main concern is that closing the window isn't releasing the memory.

Comment: When you close the popup window, even if the memory that was used by that dialog is no longer being used, it doesn't mean it will get freed immediately. The browser decides when the garbage collection will occur and you have no control on this. That's why, during develpment, you can use the "Collect garbage" button in the Timeline to force garbage collection. This is just to help with finding memory leaks, but not something you have any control over normaly.

Comment: I mentioned earlier that I had tried using the "Collect garbage" button but the memory usage didn't really go down, so the issue seems to be something else